# How do I make this menu design in android xml?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqG3Z.png)

Is there some sort of library to do this or I have to go through using the card view or linear layouts?
Also does it have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a `cardView` for you, buddy. You only need to change the `drawables` The Code below is what you see in this image:

[image: Result]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#22ad80">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bank_frame"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/more"
                    android:id="@+id/bank_image"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bank/Card settings"
                    android:id="@+id/bank_text"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bank_image"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bank_image"
                    android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/security_frame"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bank_frame"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/more"
                    android:id="@+id/security_image"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="My Security"
                    android:id="@+id/security_text"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/security_image"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/security_image"
                    android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/added_frame"
                android:layout_below="@+id/security_frame"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/more"
                    android:id="@+id/added_image"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="BVN Added"
                    android:id="@+id/added_text"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/added_image"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/added_image"
                    android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are welcome! :)  Don't hesitate to ask further questions in new posts. We try to help!